# How to configure AWS Amplify with Next JS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, aws-amplify

I am trying to connect my Next.js app (v14) with Amplify (v6).
I've already set up amplify running amplify init and creating the rest api, and installing all the dependencies.

Then, at the moment of configuring Amplify in my Layout component, I am facing some troubles. According to Amplify documentation, I should import Amplify and configure it as follows in my Layout.tsx:

```
'use client'

import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import config from '../amplifyconfiguration.json';

Amplify.configure(config, { ssr: true });
import { post } from 'aws-amplify/api';
```

So, in this way, my file (with the rest of the code included) is as follows:

```
'use client'

import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import config from '../amplifyconfiguration.json';

Amplify.configure(config, { ssr: true });
import { post } from 'aws-amplify/api';


async function postTodo() {
  
  try {
    const restOperation = post({
      apiName: "todoApi",
      path: '/todo',
      options: {
        body: {
          message: 'Mow the lawn'
        }
      }
    });
    await restOperation.response;
    console.log('POST call succeeded');
    // console.log(response);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('POST call failed: ', e);
  }
}

postTodo()

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
          {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

When the browser loads the page, it logs the message: "POST call failed:  NoCredentials: Credentials should not be empty."

I would greatly appreciate some support, as I have been trying to sort this out for more than a week without success.

Answer (score 0):

It's a issue coming with amplify v6. To solve it, you have to add ***headers*** in ***options*** inside your request :

```
  options: {
    body: {
      message: 'Mow the lawn'
    },
    headers: {
      Authorization: "test", // <--- Here is the magic line
    }
  }
```